# Construct an absolute URL without circumventing $location's abstraction

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs application I use $location's html5-mode, which handily includes a fallback for browsers not supporting the html5 history api.

I need to generate a URL pointing into my application and would like to avoid hardwiring it. Instead, I would like to leverage $location or underlying mechanisms.

Example: I need the url to have the `$location.path()` `/my/subpath`. In a browser with html5-support the url would be `http://example.com/my/subpath`, in a browser without it would be `http://example.com/#!/my/subpath`.

I tried to find the mechanism that is used for anchor rewriting in the angular sources but could not find it.

Is what I am planning possible or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

var path = window.location.hash.substr(1);

Of course you should check the HTML 5 support in the browser before using either of the APIs

Comment: So you propose to manually sniff browser support for the history api and then construct the url either with or without hash. That would most probably work but effectively circumvent angular's mechanisms, wouldn't it? This is what I am trying to avoid.